# VC++ Redist install passively without restart always restarting

Tags: visual-c++, inno-setup, vcredist

I'm trying to install VC++ Redist without any user input using the following code. I do not want system restart as well – so supplied `/norestart` flag

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/redistributing-visual-cpp-files#command-line-options-for-the-redistributable-packages

```
[Run]
Filename: "{tmp}\VC_redist.x64.exe"; \
    Parameters: "/passive /Q:a /c:""msiexec /qb /norestart /i vcredist.msi"" "; \
    StatusMsg: Installing VC++ RunTime...
```

But after the install, the setup tries to restart the machine automatically

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The VC++ Redist probably schedules some files to be replaced after next restart. Inno Setup detects that and restarts the computer after it finishes.

You can disable Inno Setup from detecting this using [`RestartIfNeededByRun` directive](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_restartifneededbyrun):

> When set to `yes`, and a program executed in the `[Run]` section queues files to be replaced on the next reboot (by calling `MoveFileEx` or by modifying wininit.ini), Setup will detect this and prompt the user to restart the computer at the end of installation.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This fixed my issue. Nice to meet the author of WinSCP btw.